# Right click to query temporal tables not working

Tags: sql-server, management-studio-express, temporal-tables

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2016 loaded with Microsoft's test database (WideWorldImporters) but for some reason, any table that is a temporal table does not give me the option of right clicking and selecting the last 1000 rows as all other non-temporal tables allow.

Am I missing something which needs to be installed or is there an alternative way of querying the table for data?

Comment: Temp tables only exist for the user session that created them. So you can only query them if you are running the query from that session.

Comment: @JacobH:i think he is talking about temporal tables

Comment: This appears to be either a bug or - more likely - lack of support in SSMS. To be fair, using these SSMS editing features has always been problematic. You're better off writing your own queries to view or edit rows.

Comment: i am not able to repro it,i just created a table and was able to right click and get 1000 rows

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables Documentation says temporal tables supported starting in SQL 2017, op using SSMS 2016. Maybe needs to upgrade SSMS?

Comment: sounds like that is the situation, I'm definitely using 2016 at the moment.

Comment: my ssms version is `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17099.0
` if that helps

Comment: that one is from help,but actual version naming while downloading is v17.0

Answer (score -1):

Right Clicking does not work. But in the session that created the table you can do any kind of query that can be done against any other table.

Comment: A temporal table is not a temp table (local or global).